# Error in accessing file uploaded file in google colab

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory, google-notebook

I upload **final_half.sqlite** file in google colab. While reading the file it is giving me the error as below. Could anyone tell me how to solve this?

`DatabaseError: database disk image is malformed`

I uploaded the file in google colab as follows

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3
from google.colab import files
uploaded = files.upload()
```

I checked the status of the uploaded file

```
for fn in uploaded.keys():
  print('User uploaded file "{name}" with length {length} bytes'.format(
      name=fn, length=len(uploaded[fn])))
```

User uploaded file "final_half.sqlite" with length 7208960 bytes

```
for name, data in uploaded.items():
  with open('final_half.sqlite', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(data)
    print ('saved file', name)
    con = sqlite3.connect(name)
    print(con)
    sorted_data = pd.read_sql_query("""SELECT * FROM Reviews_half""", con)
```

Error:

```
DatabaseError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/io/sql.py in execute(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1408             else:
-> 1409                 cur.execute(*args)
   1410             return cur

DatabaseError: database disk image is malformed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change these lines

```
for name, data in uploaded.items():
  with open('final_half.sqlite', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(data)
    print ('saved file', name)
    con = sqlite3.connect(name)
```

To just

```
con = sqlite3.connect('final_half.sqlite')
```

The file is already saved, you don't need to write it again.